# Gstreamer unable to play audio through rtspsrc

Tags: windows, audio, gstreamer, rtsp

I am having trouble to play the audio from the rtsp server, i have no problem for the video playback, but some error occurred while i tried to play audio, 
the following is the command used to play video:

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin>gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.2.116/axis-media/media.amp latency=0 !decodebin ! autovideosink
```

however, when i change the autovideosink to autoaudiosink, which as in follow:

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin>gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.2.116/axis-media/media.amp latency=0 !decodebin ! autoaudiosink
```

i get the errors below:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2933): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1:
streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
```

I am new to both stackoverflow and Gstreamer, any helps from you would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to thiagoss's reply , I have my first success on playing both video and audio using the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.2.116/axis-media/media.amp latency=0 name=src src. ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink src. ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC rtspsrc will output one pad for each stream (video and audio might be separate) so you could be linking your video output to an audiosink.

You can run with -v to see the caps on each pad and verify this. Then you can properly link by using pad names in gst-launch-1.0:

Something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.2.116/axis-media/media.amp latency=0 name=src src.stream_0 !decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Check the correct stream_%u number to use for each stream to have it linked correctly.

You can also just be missing a videoconvert before the videosink. I'd also test that.

Comment: hi thiagoss, i do not have enough of reputation to up vote your answer, i would like to express my greatest thanks here!